# Parse out Y-M-D from Y-M-D H-M-S UTC sql bigquery

Tags: sql, date, datetime, parsing, google-bigquery

I need to parse out `'%Y%m%d'` from the column in BigQuery. My data looks like this:

```
datetime_published
2000-09-25 13:28:15 UTC
2018-12-22 16:03:00 UTC
2018-05-04 03:05:00 UTC
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', datetime_published) as date
```

The error message: `No matching signature for function PARSE_DATE for argument types: STRING, TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: PARSE_DATE(STRING, STRING)`
Desired output:
`2000-09-25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just convert to a date?

```
select date(datetime)
```

Note:  This works for both `datetime` and `timestamp` values.  These are different in BigQuery.  You have a `timestamp` column which you have called `datetime` -- a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: I have edited the question and renamed the column. I have tried `select date(datetime_published)`, but for some reason, it thinks this is a function. The error message is: `Function not found: datetime_published `

Comment: @Chique_Code . . . That code should not generate that error.  You would have a `datetime_published(. . .)` for a function call.

Comment: and yet it does... This is an entire code. That should be pretty straightforward... `select datetime_published(datetime) as publish_date from 'metadata_table' limit 200` Error: `Function not found: datetime_published at [1:8] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.`

Comment: Why do you have single quotes around the table name?  And why do you have `datetime_published(datetime)`?  That code has *nothing* to do with this answer.

Comment: It's backticks, changed it to single quotes here, to have a code in code block.